# Why do I get reference error for fetch when I do unit tests using Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm new to unit tests using Jest but basically I have a file `client.js`  looking like this:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
const fetcher = () => {

    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/').then(res => res.json);
}


module.exports = {add, fetcher};
```

The `client.test.js` is as follows:

```
const client = require('../client');

test('Testing addition', () => {
    expect(client.add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});

test('Yet another addition', () => {
    expect(client.add(3, 10)).toBe(13);
});



test('Testing a promise', () => {
    return client.fetcher().then(data => {
        expect(data).toBe(1824);
    })
});
```

When I try to run tests it throws an error `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined`. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can't test client-side code on the server. `fetch` only exists inside a browser environment.

Comment: Note that it's `res => res.json()`

Comment: @ChrisG So what framework should I use for unit tests for client-side?

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- Define a `fetch` function somewhere (e.g. by loading the node-fetch module that is available on NPM)
- Use the `--experimental-fetch` flag when you run Node (and make sure it is version [17.5 or newer](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V17.md#2022-02-10-version-1750-current-ruyadorno)

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea — Not if you run it with Node.js.

Comment: Curiously I ran into problems out of the box using `--experimental-fetch` it seems like Jest overwrites the globals and I lost access to `fetch()` / `Response` / `Request` etc - I was able to resolve by injecting them in `jest.config.js` - `globals: { fetch, Response, Request }` - feels dirty - but I assume in a month or two someone else will fix it properly!

Comment: How do we get jest test to use the --experimental-fetch flag?

Comment: Or better yet, running jest using node 18 where we don't need that flag anymore, jest still throws "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined", but I can execute the same code just fine :(